# finding the minimal distance of 2 cars without trigonometry

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, word-problem

Given $\angle ABC =120^{\circ}$, and the distance $AB=700\,\text{km}$:

A car is driving from point $A$ to point $B$  at the speed of $80\,\mathrm{km}\cdot\mathrm{h}^{-1}$.

A second car is driving (started same time when the first car) from point $B$ to point $C$ at the speed of $100\,\mathrm{km}\cdot\mathrm{h}^{-1}$.

For how long since the two cars started driving, their distance will be **minimal**?

**Remark**: **no** trigonometry is allowed.

I tried to build right triangles but it didn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The angle is $120$ not $90$ that's why i don't understand how to solve without using trigonometry.

Comment: What do you mean by trigonometry here? All answers are going to implicitly build triangles at some point - even the distance formula is just the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: i mean, i can use Pythagorean Theorem which is not involving the need of trigonometry. distance formula as well. it's a question that given  before learning trigonometry at all. only plain simple distance formula /Pythagorean Theorem or any basic geometric use.

Answer (score 2):

For $\angle ABC=90^o$: $$\min_{0 \leq  t \leq \frac{70}{8}}{(700-80t)^2+(100t)^2}$$ this can be rewritten as $$700^2+\min_{0 \leq  t \leq \frac{70}{8}}{(80^2+100^2)t^2-2\cdot80\cdot700t}$$ As a quadratic with roots $t=0$ and $t=\frac{2\cdot80\cdot700}{80^2+100^2}$ it is minimized at the midpoint of the roots, that is in $$t^*=\frac{80\cdot700}{80^2+100^2}=3.41$$

Comment: i didn't understand your hint, and it should be, according the answer : $t=2.5$ and in your function it's $t=3.41$

Comment: oh i made a mistake.. see my edit qustion.

Comment: @roy, good luck

Comment: terribly sorry for that.. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

Take a look at the following figure. I think that it will help you to go through.

$1.$ Write the coordinates of the cars at time $t$.

$2.$ Compute their distance $d=d(t)$ using their coordinates.

$3.$ Minimize the function $d^2=d^2(t)$ where $0 \le t \le \frac{700}{80}$.

[image]

Comment: i feel bad for the effort and time, but the angle is $120$ not $90$, but thank you!

Comment: @roy: Take a look at the new pic. :) Hope this help. Take care when you write questions. :)

Comment: thank you:) i will next time! i didn't get how did you now those values and also how you continue from there.

Comment: @roy: Try to write down the coordinates of the cars at time $t$. It is a hint and you should discover the details by yourself! :)

Comment: ok, ill try just it seems like you used parametric line by vector and i don't know that material.

Comment: @roy: What ever you are going to use, you should came up with this result no matter what you are using. You can compute the slope of $BC$. Can't you?

Comment: ill think about it, for know i can't see how. thanks

Comment: @roy: Thinking is good! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Say we assume the x-axis to be along $BC$. The origin coincides with $B$.

Thus equation of $AB$ is $y=\tan 120^\circ \cdot x$ i.e. $y=-\sqrt{3}x$

So by the problem, $x^2+3x^2=700^2 \Rightarrow x=\pm 350$

As evident from this problem, here $x=-350$

Hence the co-ordinates of $A=(-350,350\sqrt{3})$

So the instantaneous co-ordinates of 1st car are $(80 \cos 60^\circ t - 350, 350\sqrt{3} - 80 \sin 60^\circ t)$ and that of 2nd car is $(100t,0)$.

So you have to minimise the function $f(x)=\sqrt{(80 \cos 60^\circ t - 350 - 100t)^2+(350\sqrt{3} - 80 \sin 60^\circ t)^2}$

or in other words,

you have to minimise the function $$g(x)=f^2(x)=(80 \cos 60^\circ t - 350 - 100t)^2+(350\sqrt{3} - 80 \sin 60^\circ t)^2$$
$$=(40t - 350 - 100t)^2+(350\sqrt{3} - 40\sqrt{3} t)^2$$
$$=( 350 + 60t)^2+(350\sqrt{3} - 40\sqrt{3} t)^2$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you but i wanted to know if it solvable without using trigonometry.

Comment: @roy I used co-ordinate geometry and calculus. Where did you find trigo?

Comment: hmm $sin,cos$..

Comment: @roy That's elementary usage.... Anyways..